# What am I getting compiling errors for the variable isOperator?

Tags: java

Whenever I compile this code for my project, it always gets an error. I am trying to program an actual calculator for my programming class. When I compiled it, bluej said "It cannot find symbol - variable isOperator."

```
import java.util.*;
public class InfixtoPostFix
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    //insert nested class SyntaxErroeException.
    public static class SyntaxErrorException extends Exception{
        SyntaxErrorException (String message){
            super(message);
        }
    }
    //data fields
    /**The operator Stack */
    private Stack<Character> operatorStack;
    /** THe operator */
    private static final String OPERATORS = "+-*/";
    /** The precedence of the operators mathces the order in Operators */
    private static final int[] PRECENDENCE = {0,1,1,2,2,2};
    /** Postfix string */
    private StringBuilder postfix;

    public String convert(String infix) throws SyntaxErrorException{
        operatorStack = new Stack<Character>();
        postfix = new StringBuilder();

        String[] tokens = infix.split("\\s+");
        //process each token in the infix string
        try{
            for(String nextToken : tokens){
                char firstChar = nextToken.charAt(0);
                //is it an operand
                if(Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(firstChar) || Character.isDigit(firstChar)){
                    postfix.append(nextToken);
                    postfix.append(' ');
                }else if(isOperator(firstChar)){
                    //is it an operator
                    processOpperator(firstChar);
                }else{
                    throw new SyntaxErrorException("Unexpected Character Encountered: " + firstChar);
                }
            }

            //pop any remaing opperators
            //appen them to post fix
            while(!operatorStack.empty()){
                char op = operatorStack.pop();
                postfix.append(op);
                postfix.append(' ');
            }

            //assert =: stack is empty return result
            return postfix.toString();
        }catch(EmptyStackException e){
            throw new SyntaxErrorException("Syntax error: The stack is empty");
        }
    }

    private void processOpperator(char op){
        if(operatorStack.empty()){
            operatorStack.push(op);
        }else{
            //peek the operator stack and ler topOp be the top operator
            char topOp = operatorStack.peek();
            if(precedence(op) > precedence(topOp)){
                operatorStack.push(op);
            }else{
                //pop all stacked operators with equal or higher prededence than op
                while(!operatorStack.empty() && precedence(op) <= precedence(op)){
                    operatorStack.pop();
                    postfix.append(topOp);
                    postfix.append(' ');
                    if(!operatorStack.empty()){
                        topOp = operatorStack.peek();
                    }
                }
                //assert: operator stack is empty or current operator precedence > top of stack operator preceence
                operatorStack.push(op);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isOperator(char ch){
        return isOperator.indexOf(ch) != 1;
    }

    private int precedence(char op){
        return PRECEDENCE[OPERATORS>indexOf(op)];
    }

}
```

Comment: variable `isOperator` is not defined inside `isOperator()` method?

Comment: What 'isOperator.indexOf' is supposed to mean inside 'isOperator' method body?

Answer (score 1):

In method `isOperator`, you write: `return isOperator.indexOf(ch) != 1;`, you use a variable named `isOperator`, but I suppose you shoule use your static member variable `OPERATORS`; and I suppose you shoule compare the return value of `indexOf` by `-1`, not `1`, if you want to check if the `ch` exists in `OPERATORS`, so change

```
private boolean isOperator(char ch){
    return isOperator.indexOf(ch) != 1;
}
```

to

```
private boolean isOperator(char ch){
    return OPERATORS.indexOf(ch) != -1;
}
```

Comment: @mttdbrd I've tried my best to doped out what OP want to do.

Comment: Excellent detective work. I figured that OP wanted isOperator to be a String but didn't figure out which one it was. Nice work.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler isn't lying to you or being obscure, when it said it cannot find "variable isOperator". Look through the code. You are using an undeclared variable "isOperator" in:
        return isOperator.indexOf(ch) != 1;

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean isOperator(char ch){
    return isOperator.indexOf(ch) != 1;
           ^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

You never defined that variable anywhere. The only reference to `isOperator` in your code is to the method. Did you mean to put something else there?

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean isOperator(char ch){
    return isOperator.indexOf(ch) != 1;
}
```

You have several problems with this code. isOperator.indexOf(ch) suggests that your code thinks isOperator is a String. The problem is that the String it came from is not in scope for this method call. You may want to simply check the String index earlier instead of using a method to do this check. The index should already be known to you before you pass to this method.